# Azure Autoscaling - what options do I have?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I've got a running service on Azure and I'd like it to autoscale.

I've tried Wasabi (azure autoscaling from MS) - it didn't work for me.

So I'm looking for other third-party services.

I've found only 2 - opstera (which is closed for new customers) and paraleap which seems without customers.

Any other options for scaling azure?

Thanks

Comment: Specifying why Wasabi didin't work for you would help suggest alternatives.

Comment: The reactive rules didn't work - I've worked with Microsoft support and wasabi support in vain. So had to leave it...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where you got the information from, but AzureWatch @ http://www.paraleap.com has a decent amount of customers and is adding new users on a daily basis.

AzureWatch is also in the final stages of migrating its configuration tool away from a desktop tool to an online one.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

You can try [AzureCheck](http://azurecheck.cloudapp.net). It provides monitoring data and manual as well as auto scalling options. You can try it out with free account.

Comment: Ruchit you are right it's provides good option to scale application based on CPU & Memory.

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Self-Scaling Portal](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-Self-Scaling-8516b857) could be a good start for you - it has an example of scaling policy (ScaleManager.cs file) and a ton of useful wrapper code to call Management API (ManagenebtService.cs). The license is very permissive. Using pieces of this thing you could craft your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are three options to achieve auto scaling in Azure.

1.Tools based(WASABi, MetricsHub)
2.Custom scripting 
3.Windows Azure Autoscale

Both Azure Autoscale and scripting can be used, only for the basic level auto  scaling.
WASABi and MetricsHub can be used for advance level auto scaling. WASABi is an application block which part of Entlib-5.0. There is a great article about this on MSDN blog.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2013/07/02/windows-azure-autoscaling-now-built-in.aspx

I Hope this will help you.

Regards,
-Gopal